# PHP list preserves normal array order in 5.* while assigning values(instead of backwards order)

Tags: php, arrays

According to the PHP official documentation following example shouldn't sort the input array because of reversed order of assigning array values to list variables in PHP 5, so, the $input[$j] which is very last element of array should be assigned to list's $input[$j] because it is very first element, and normal order should be preserved. But that doesn't happen. The behaviour of the function is same in both PHP 5 and PHP 7 versions, and I wonder why does that happen. I think that it should be connected to php zval array representation, but I do not understand how exactly. So, It would be cool if somebody could explain me such behaviour of the list construction.

```
function bubbleSort(&$input)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($input); $i++)
    {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($input) - $i - 1; $j++)
        {
            if ($input[$j] > $input[$j+1])
            {
                list($input[$j], $input[$j+1]) = array($input[$j+1], $input[$j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

$input = array(3, 5, 1, 22, 0, 1, 11, 30, 4);
bubbleSort($input);
var_dump($input);
```

Comment: [PHP works fine](https://3v4l.org/HfcuG) (i.e. as you expect it to work), your implementation of [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is incorrect.

Comment: Values should be assigned from left to right in 5 version according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php - so check, in your example order should be preserved, like (0, 1, 2, 3, 4), but the output is (0, 2, 1, 3, 4). My example is correct for PHP 7 version, but it works in both, which isn't expected behaviour.

Comment: Oh, it seems your expectations are incorrect too. The values **are** assigned from left to right. But, before assigning anything to the variables in the left-hand side member, the value in the rhs member is computed. And that value is an array that happens to be initialized with values from `$input`. The assignment `list($input[$j], $input[$j+1]) = array($input[$j+1], $input[$j])` does not copy `$input[$j+1]` into `$input[$j]`, it copies the first item of `array(...)` into it. `array($input[$j+1], $input[$j])` and `$input` do not share anything.

Comment: So, now I got the idea - it does not and could not reindex existing array, just executes assigning operator in order from rightmost to leftmost operand, but if we are creating a new array it will populate it in order similar to assigning order with keeping element indices(rightmost to rightmost, leftmost to leftmost and so on) - so it will be reversed, yeah. It also points that everything is fine with my sort, since list operates with values of existing array. https://3v4l.org/nB8sl

Answer (score 0):

I see you found your issue with your function, but I wanted to post an answer here because I found the information about the changes to the list construct to be confusing as well.  This link was super helpful:

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.list.order

Basically, PHP 7 changes, what I'm thinking of as, the *timing* of the assignments, so in PHP 5, it assigns the right most value in the list arguments first and the left most value is assigned last, so if you had:

```
list($a[], $a[], $a[]) = array('x', 'y', 'z')
```

Then the right most $a[] is going to be assigned first, so you will have

```
$a[0] == 'z'
```

The mapping of the values onto the variables in the list construct is the same, just the timing is different.

In PHP 7, the left most variable is assigned first, so in the example above:

```
$a[0] == 'x'
```